# SCP from an Ubuntu device to an Ubuntu VM in Windows

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ssh

I am attempting to copy some files from an Ubuntu device to an Ubuntu VM inside of Windows 10. The VM is running in VirtualBox, the network type is set to Bridged as that was what I found solved other peoples problem. However I am still not able to copy.

I am executing the `scp` command from the VM's console. The full command I am attempting to run is: 
`scp username@ipaddress thisVMUsername@thisVMipaddress`

Edit:
I can successfully `scp` using `scp username@ipaddress /some/local/file`

However what if I want to `scp` from someone else's machine to mine in the VM for example this doesn't work: `scp /local/file VMUsername@VMipaddress`

Comment: Please have a look here : https://superuser.com/a/686527/201468

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error it's throwing for you, might be a syntax error.
If you are logged into the Ubuntu VM then it should be as simple as `scp username@ipaddress:file.txt /some/place/local/`. The man page for SCP is confusing and not very clear.

Have a looksee at this page for a few examples: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you know what it would be if someone else wanted to copy the file to my machine, from theirs?

Comment: That would be `scp file.txt your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory`